# Join series with repeated index on dataframe where column values are equal to the index in the series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a series and dataframe like:

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([10,20,11,12,30,34],
    index=["red","red","blue","blue","green","green"])
s.index.name="numbers"

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "color":["red","green","blue","blue","red","green"],
    "id":[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

I want to add the values in `s` to the column in `df` in the same order as they appear where the index of `s` is equal to `df["color"]` i.e

```py
pd.some_function(df,s,left_on="color",right_index=True)

color   id    numbers
red      1      10
green    2      30
blue     3      11
blue     4      12
red      5      20
green    6      34
```

I have tried `pd.merge`, `pd.join` etc. but I simply cannot make it work (without looping over `df`, filtered by `color`, add the data from `s` and then concat it at the end)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to set up a unique key for the `merge`:

```
idx1 = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
# [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
idx2 = df.groupby('color').cumcount()
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

s.index.name="color"
out = (df
   .merge(s.reset_index(name='number'),
          left_on=['color', idx2], right_on=['color', idx1])
   .drop(columns='key_1')
)
```

variant:

```
s.index.name="color"
out = (df
   .assign(idx=df.groupby('color').cumcount())
   .merge(s.reset_index(name='number')
           .assign(idx=s.groupby(level=0).cumcount().values),
          left_on=['color', 'idx'], right_on=['color', 'idx'])
    .drop(columns='idx')
)
```

output:

```
   color  id  number
0    red   1      10
1  green   2      30
2   blue   3      11
3   blue   4      12
4    red   5      20
5  green   6      34
```

Comment: I would never come up with that solution ... Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yep, @mozway is the best and comes up with great solutions! +1

Comment: Thanks @Scott I appreciate your support ;)